# Why i can’t see light option in mesh?

Tags: mesh, lighting

[image: img]I was working on the spaceship when decided to add another light source, but all of the sudden light option in mesh is gone

Comment: Hi :). You're in Edit mode. Switch to Object mode to add lights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're in a sculpting mode.

Comment: Well, although this is marked as accepted answer, the screenshot clearly shows _Edit Mode_, not _Sculpt Mode_ so I'm not sure what you mean by "a sculpting mode".